# Bigquery SQL: Create new table. Split monthly value to daily

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create a new table from the existing data:

| date | store | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-10 | a | 3000 |
| 2022-01-10 | b | 2500 |

And finally the targettable should look like:

| date | store | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-10 | a | 3000/sum day of months = 96,77 |
| 2022-02-10 | a | 3000/sum day of months |
| 2022-03-10 | a | 3000/sum day of months |
| 2022-04-10 | a | 3000/sum day of months |
| .... to last day of the month | a | 3000/sum day of months |
| 2022-01-10 | b | 2500/sum day of months |
| 2022-02-10 | b | 2500/sum day of months |
| 2022-03-10 | b | 2500/sum day of months |
| ... | b | 2500/sum day of months |

The query should create a new table with new rows for each day of the month. The cost should devided by the day of the month to split the cost.
I found a query but cant implement it to my problem!

```
with targettable as (
SELECT date('2022-01-10') as targetdate, 31 as units
 )
 select days,
   last_day(targettable.targetdate) enddate,
  units / extract(day from days) as units
   from targettable
   cross join unnest(generate_date_array(targettable.targetdate, 
   last_day(targettable.targetdate))) as days
```

Thank you!

Comment: the sample data does not has units. did you mean cost?

Comment: yes, I mean cost.

Comment: What's the problem? this seems to work

Comment: yes, it works but how can I implement the query to my specific problem to create a new table.

Comment: For store a the value 96,77 should be in everey row for store a in october.

Comment: I have added an answer on your other open question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70668433/bigquery-split-monthly-data-into-days - I think this is a duplicate and should be closed.